# Get distinct rows when filtering and using dynamic order by

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

My first version of the question was confusing, I need to make smaller chunks.
If a user can filter products from a website, one product should occur only once in the list.
Because of joins this code gives me two same products, how do I solve that?
I think I need a solution without using distinct because it will give me headache later on.

code from AW2012:

```
    declare @safetystocklevel int
    set @safetystocklevel  = 1000
    declare @status int
    set @status  = 2

    select * from Production.Product p
    inner join Purchasing.ProductVendor pv on p.ProductID = pv.ProductID
    inner join Purchasing.Vendor v on v.BusinessEntityID = pv.BusinessEntityID
    inner join Production.ProductDocument pd on p.ProductID = pd.ProductID
    inner join Production.Document d on d.DocumentNode = pd.DocumentNode
    WHERE 
    (@safetystocklevel = '' or p.SafetyStockLevel = @safetystocklevel)
    and (@status = '' or d.Status = @status)
```

output:
ProductId   Name
506 Reflector
506 Reflector

Edit:

Thanks, I now use Group by to get distinct rows.
Yeah, maybe using group by works for me, Im gonna do some testing now.....

Hi again

I want all products to be searchable, so I guess I need left outer joins to achieve that.
When I add dynamic order by I get into trouble, more rows are added. 
Probably because I must add poh.Status to the group by.
There are 504 rows in the product table, this query returns 776 rows.
(I have removed the filtering in WHERE since it is not interesting now, and Im joining to other tables now just to get more rows to play with)

Code:

```
    declare @sortType nvarchar(50)
    set @sortType  = 'Status'
    select p.ProductID,
    CASE WHEN @sortType = 'Status' THEN poh.Status END as Status,
    CASE WHEN @sortType = 'ProductId' THEN p.ProductID END as ProductId
    from Production.Product p
    left outer join Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail pod on p.ProductID = pod.ProductID
    left outer join Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader poh on poh.PurchaseOrderID = pod.PurchaseOrderID
    left outer join Production.ProductDocument ppd on ppd.ProductID = p.ProductID
    left outer join Production.Document pd on pd.DocumentNode = ppd.DocumentNode
    group by p.ProductID, poh.Status
    ORDER BY
        CASE WHEN @sortType = 'Status' THEN poh.Status END ASC,
        CASE WHEN @sortType = 'ProductId' THEN p.ProductID END ASC
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? It is not really clear what you want to acheive. Can you perhaps show a (presumably handmade) table that shows (some of) the data you expect to get?

Comment: @CliffSmith, I suppose since you are using distinct, that one of the tables is 1-n, in that case which one? I mean, what is causing the resultset to have multiple product rows, where you only want one?

Comment: The question is updated

Comment: Include all the fields and check what makes it duplicate. And, if you to remove the duplicates then include the condition that causes two rows..... or include the column in the select query.

Comment: @Viji - Of course I can find the duplicates,
Title in Production.Document is one example. But Im not sure what you mean.

Comment: you can use Group By ProductId, Name, to select the single row, if you are not planning to include distinct. But I'll prefer "distinct" if you  are not using any aggregate value in select clause.

Comment: @Cliff : My guess is each product has diff status in PurchaseOrderHeader, because of that you are getting 776 rows, instead of 504 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Group By ProductId, Name, to select the single row, if you are not planning to include distinct. But I'll prefer "distinct" if you are not using any aggregate value in select clause.

```
select p.ProductId, p.Name from Production.Product p
inner join Purchasing.ProductVendor pv on p.ProductID = pv.ProductID
inner join Purchasing.Vendor v on v.BusinessEntityID = pv.BusinessEntityID
inner join Production.ProductDocument pd on p.ProductID = pd.ProductID
inner join Production.Document d on d.DocumentNode = pd.DocumentNode
WHERE 
(@safetystocklevel = '' or p.SafetyStockLevel = @safetystocklevel)
and (@status = '' or d.Status = @status)
GROUP BY  p.ProductId, p.Name
```

Comment: If Group BY clause, works for you, can u please accept the answer and do up vote.

Comment: @Cliff : My guess is each product has diff status in PurchaseOrderHeader, because of that you are getting 776 rows, instead of 504 rows

Comment: Yes, I understand. Is this solvable or am I demanding to much of sql? I would like to solve it in a SP, instead of having client do the sorting.

Comment: In that case, have it in IF statement. IF sortby = status, have separate query, if sortby = product, have separate query... if you have both in same query, and not using distinct will give two rows

Comment: Yeah, it's either that or dynamic sql. I was hoping for something better, since the real code Im working with is bigger. It's not gonna be nice to solve this either way. Thank you for your help.